# How can I find node within XAML with SelectNodes?

Tags: xaml, powershell

I'd like to find Button node within XAML in following PowerShell script. But I can't find it.

```
[xml]$xaml1 = @' 
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="640">
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="99,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" Height="30"/>
</Window>
'@
$xaml1.SelectNodes("//Button")  | ForEach {
    $_.Name
}
# No OUTOUT from above code!
```

When I delete line 3 and 4, it works.

```
[xml]$xaml2 = @' 
<Window
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="640">
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="99,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" Height="30"/>
</Window>
'@
$xaml2.SelectNodes("//Button")  | ForEach {
    $_.Name
}
# OUTPUT of above code:
Button
```

How can I find node within XAML with SelectNodes?

Comment: Specify the namespace parameter. Examples: [Using PowerShell, how do I add multiple namespaces (one of which is the default namespace)?](//stackoverflow.com/a/5279297) and [.SelectSingleNode in Powershell script using xPath not working on extracting values from web.config file](//stackoverflow.com/a/18881581)

Comment: Thank you for comment. Based on your feedback I tried following. But, unfortunately, it does not work.
    [System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager] $nsmgr = xaml1.NameTable;
    $nsmgr.AddNamespace($null, "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
    $xaml1.SelectSingleNode("//Button", $nsmgr)

Comment: FWIW, it works if you add non-$null prefixes e.g. `x` and use it in the selector too. Wait for someone else who actually knows this stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your effort/
I tried with prefix "x" like "x:Button" and it works.
But, unfortunately, it is not usable to display GUI using XAML.
I will wait someone.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution by  checking property of each node.The following code works fine.

```
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*") | ? {$_.LocalName -eq "Button"} | % {
   # action for each Button Node
}
```

The following is sample code using above.

```
[xml]$xaml = @' 
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="button0" Content="Button0"/>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button1"/>
        <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button2"/>
        <Button x:Name="button3" Content="Button3"/>
        <Button x:Name="button4" Content="Button4"/>
        <Button x:Name="button5" Content="Button5"/>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Height="150">
            <TextBlock x:Name="msg" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
'@

$reader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml
$frm = [System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)

$scrollViewer = $frm.FindName("scrollViewer")
$msg = $frm.FindName("msg")
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*") | ? {$_.LocalName -eq "Button"} | % {
    $button = $frm.FindName($_.Name)
    $button.add_Click({
        $msg.Inlines.add($this.Content + " pushed`n")
        $scrollViewer.ScrollToBottom()
    })
}

$result = $frm.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry the followings are code:

```
[xml]$xaml1 = @' 
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="640">
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="99,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" Height="30"/>
</Window>
'@
[System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager] $nsmgr = $xaml1.NameTable;
$nsmgr.AddNamespace($null, 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation');
$xaml1.SelectSingleNode("//Button", $nsmgr)
```

Comment: It's not clear from the intro "I'm sorry the followings are code" (sic) whether this is a solution to the problem or a refinement of the question. Can you clarify? Remember, if you need to change the question after asking it, you can ***edit*** the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$xaml1.Window.Button
```

Comment: Thanks. It works.
But What I want to do is find many buttons in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object {Set-Variable -Name ($*.Name) -Value $Form.FindName($*.Name)}

Now you have the Controls as Variable...

if the Name of a Button is "button" you have a variable $button in Powershell.
add a click like this then...
$button.add_click({write-host "clicked!!"})