# How to search workflows' xaml?

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm, power-automate

I am using PowerShell to query information about CRM workflows (AKA Power Automate Flows). Specifically, I need to be able to search the flows' actions. I've been able to view the flows' xaml using this:

```
$myworkflows =  Get-CrmRecords -EntityLogicalName workflow -Fields *

        foreach($workflow in $myworkflows)
            {
               $workflow.values.xaml
            }
```

But I can't dig any deeper into it to find specific information on the flows' actions. I found [this link](https://www.ecanarys.com/Blogs/ArticleID/149/How-Microsoft-Dynamics-CRM-workflow-definitions-are-stored-in-the-SQL-Database) that shows you can get the information I'm looking for from the xaml, but no information about how! Any ideas?

Comment: What does `$workflow.values.xaml` contain/output? A string with the raw XAML markup?

Comment: If it is raw xaml, then you should be able to read it in as [xml] and use xpath methods like SelectNodes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43026822/how-can-i-find-node-within-xaml-with-selectnodes

Comment: @mathias r. jessen  I am extremely unfamiliar with xaml, but the output looks very very similar to the sample output at the linked blog

Comment: Cool, then you can just parse it and work with it as-is, either as generic XML (`$xmlDocument = [xml]$workflow.values.xaml`), or by using the `XamlReader` class referenced by @Cpt.Whale above.

Comment: Got this error: `Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 2, position 3."
At line:39 char:11
+           $xmlDocument = [xml]$workflow.values.xaml
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastToXmlDocument`